# Node.js request body parameter returns null, but request query works

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm currently trying to retrieve the "botnum" parameter i have set. In my router file, when I do console.log(req.query.botnum), it returns me with the exact number im looking for, based on the value i have set. However, when i do console.log(req.body.botnum) whilst making a post request, it returns undefined.

url : http://localhost:50000/counselling-2?botnum=2

Relevant code in EJS file for counselling page

```
<input value="<%= botnum %>" type="hidden" id="botnum"/>
```

Relevant code in EJS file for selection page

```
 <script>
        function selectExercise(){
            var url = document.getElementById('exercise').value
            if(url != 'Default') {
                window.location = `counselling-${url}?botnum=${url}`;
            }
        }
    </script>

<body>
  <option value="1">Exercise 1 - Presciption Collection (methotrexate and folic acid)</option>
    <option value="2">Exercise 2 - Presciption Collection (glycerol suppositories)</option>
    <option value="3">Exercise 3 - Travel Sickness Enquiry</option>
</body>
```

Router code

```
router.get('/counselling-2',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.query.botnum);
    res.render('counselling-2', {
        botnum: req.query.botnum
    })
})
```

server.js code

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/send-msg',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body.botnum);
    console.log(req.body);
    runSample(req.body.MSG,req.body.botnum).then(data=>{
        res.send({Reply:data})
    })
    
})
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Update : My /send-msg is called in index.js

```
unction fetchmsg(){

     var url = '/send-msg';
      
      const data = new URLSearchParams();
      for (const pair of new FormData(document.getElementById("mymsg"))) {
          data.append(pair[0], pair[1]);
          
      }   
      console.log("abc",data)
        fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST',
          body:data
        }).then(res => res.json())
         .then(response => {
           
          console.log(response);
        serverMessage(response.Reply);     
            
            var botReply =  new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(response.Reply)
            if(botSpeak ==true){
             speechSynthesis.speak(botReply);
                }
            
         })
    
          .catch(error => console.error('Error h:', error));
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `/send-msg` ?

Comment: @NullDev I've updated the post to include the code snippet for that, my bad, should have included it in the first place

Comment: Setting `body` to an instance of `URLSearchParams` should set the `Content-Type` header correctly. If you check your browser's network tab, is the POST request of type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: @RickN Yes, upon inspecting my network in chrome, it shows post request type value "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"

Comment: @NullDev Thanks, managed to figure out the problem, it was because I did not append the data the place where i call my /send-msg

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @NullDev in the comments. Have managed to find the source of the problem by appending the code in my index.js

```
 function fetchmsg(){

     var url = '/send-msg';
      
      const data = new URLSearchParams();
      for (const pair of new FormData(document.getElementById("mymsg"))) {
          data.append(pair[0], pair[1]); 
      }   
    
     var botnum = document.getElementById("botnum").value;
     data.append("botnum",botnum);
     console.log("BOTNUM", botnum);
   
      console.log("abc",data);
        fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST',
          body:data
        }).then(res => res.json())
         .then(response => {
           
          console.log(response);
        serverMessage(response.Reply);     
            
            var botReply =  new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(response.Reply)
            if(botSpeak ==true){
             speechSynthesis.speak(botReply);
                }
            
         })
    
          .catch(error => console.error('Error h:', error));
}
```